# GWT : how to compile multiple module result into single nocache.js file

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-compiler

Let's say I have 2 module in my gwt project and it was structured like this

```
src
- main
 - java
     module1.gwt.xml
     module2.gwt.xml
     - client
          - module1
               - stuff
          - module2
               - stuff
```

and on each module xml file

```
<module rename-to='module1'>
       ... their own entry point and stuff..
</module>

<module rename-to='module2'>
       ... their own entry point and stuff..
</module>
```

So, from this, when compile, I'll get 2 nocache.js file which is "*module1.nocache.js*" and "*module2.nocache.js*". Which is perfectly works fine by including 2 of them into HTML page.

My question are follow, is there any way I can compile multiple module and get a single nocache.js file which contains both modules inside ?

Thanks ! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your project structure should solve your problem.

Try something like this:

```
src
- main
 - java
  - module1 
     module1.gwt.xml
     - client
       - stuff
  - module2  
     module2.gwt.xml
     - client
       - stuff
```

You have to define one module which will start your application. The second module should be inherit by the first one.

Comment: Your .gwt.xml file will look like : 

`<module rename-to='module1'>
     <inherits name='module2' />
<!-- entry point if this is the main application-->
 <entry-point class="com.example.AppEntryPoint' />
</module>`

and module 2 : 
`
<module rename-to='module2'>
       ... their own entry point and stuff..
</module>
`

Comment: Note also that you can perfectly make it 2 projects